# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{\frac{3}{2}}}{(1+y)}\frac{\exp{y}}{(\exp{y}-1)^2}dy$ is convergent or divergent??

Tags: calculus, integration

How to determine whether the following integral is convergent or divergent ?:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{y^{3/2} \over1 + y}\,
{\exp\left(y\right) \over \left[\exp\left(y\right) - 1\right]^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral converges.  Near $y=0$ the integrand behaves as $y^{-1/2}$, which is integrable.  As $y \to \infty$, the integrand behaves as $y^{1/2} e^{-y}$ which is also integrable there.

Comment: @DilrukGallage Consider low order Taylor series.